# How to handle incoming TCP message and send a response in Node-RED?

Tags: node-red, tcpsocket

Using Node-RED TCP socket nodes, is there any way to handle incoming messages when the flow is acting as a TCP socket server (TCP out) that sends data to connected clients?

The idea is to allow a "is alive?" method.

Answer (score 2):

The TCP-out node can be set to "Reply" mode which when linked to a TCP-in node in "Server" mode will accept incoming connections and allow you to reply.

The following example just echo's the input back to the client.

[image]

```
[{"id":"ef432e3f1a0f275e","type":"tcp in","z":"cc3f50ef2f39f8d0","name":"","server":"server","host":"","port":"8889","datamode":"stream","datatype":"utf8","newline":"\\n","topic":"","base64":false,"tls":"","x":270,"y":160,"wires":[["825896b40c7c96b9","d24c5bbd4d73d2af"]]},{"id":"825896b40c7c96b9","type":"debug","z":"cc3f50ef2f39f8d0","name":"","active":true,"tosidebar":true,"console":false,"tostatus":false,"complete":"true","targetType":"full","statusVal":"","statusType":"auto","x":410,"y":200,"wires":[]},{"id":"d24c5bbd4d73d2af","type":"tcp out","z":"cc3f50ef2f39f8d0","name":"","host":"","port":"","beserver":"reply","base64":false,"end":false,"tls":"","x":530,"y":160,"wires":[]}]
```