# NodeRed TCP Out Success Response

Tags: tcp, iot, node-red

NodeRed instance is receiving a request on MQTT broker and sending a request to TCP server. How Can I configure TCPOUT node to send the response if message is sent successful and send back the received message. Please help.

[image]

I tried TCP request node and read documentation but still blocked

Comment: Is this what you're after? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72964576/how-to-handle-incoming-tcp-message-and-send-a-response-in-node-red

Comment: You say you've tried the TCP-request node but not described what happened or how it didn't work. We need more details about exactly what you tried and what exactly the other device is doing